# JMeter - Stop thread after error, but allow retries

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a JMeter script which makes requests to 5 different endpoints. If there's an error, that thread should be stopped.

However, I would like to retry the request to the 3rd endpoint 3 times before stopping the thread.

Here is what my script looks like:

- Thread Group (with **Stop thread** selected)

  - HTTP Request (1st endpoint)
  - HTTP Request (2nd endpoint)
  - Transaction Controller

    - While Controller

      - HTTP Request (3rd endpoint)

        - JSR223 PostProcessor (to save the response code in a variable for the while controller to check)
      - Counter (to keep track of the retry count)
    - JSR223 Assertion (to set the result as successful, so the first failed retries don't count)
  - HTTP Request (4th endpoint)
  - HTTP Request (5th endpoint)

Since I checked option **Stop thread** under Thread Group, if the first request to the 3rd endpoint fails, the thread stops and no retries are made.

If I check **Continue**, then the retries to the 3rd endpoint work as intended, but the thread doesn't stop if the requests to the other endpoints fail.

I also tried to add the following Groovy script to the JSR223 PostProcessor, but it didn't work:

```
if (prev.isStopThread()) {
    prev.setStopThread(false)
}
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" to `Continue` in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to prevent threads from stopping.

If you decide to stop the thread you can do it in 2 ways:

1. Via [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) (in conjunction with the [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller))

   [image]
2. Via any of your JSR223 Test Elements as

   ```
   prev.setStopThread(true)
   ```

You don't even need a counter, since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) While Controller exposes current iteration via `__jm__While Controller__idx` pre-defined variable

Comment: So I should do this after every request (except the 3rd one), right?